# Php replace in string

Tags: php, regex

I've got string based on current url, look like this:

```
domain.com/katalog_firm,p11.html?typ=lista&fraza=&search_group=1&search_type=1&kategoria=1&podkategoria=0&wojewodztwo=0&miejscowosc=0&page=1&limit=10
```

I want to do a pagination. How to replace in this strng page=x, and limit is choosen from dropdown so also limit=x
So I want to change exxample from above to

```
domain.com/katalog_firm,p11.html?typ=lista&fraza=&search_group=1&search_type=1&kategoria=1&podkategoria=0&wojewodztwo=0&miejscowosc=0&page=2&limit=25
```

I just want to make replacement from (page and limit)

```
domain.com/katalog_firm,p11.html?typ=lista&fraza=&search_group=1&search_type=1&kategoria=1&podkategoria=0&wojewodztwo=0&miejscowosc=0&page=1&limit=10
```

to

```
domain.com/katalog_firm,p11.html?typ=lista&fraza=&search_group=1&search_type=1&kategoria=1&podkategoria=0&wojewodztwo=0&miejscowosc=0&page=2&limit=25
```

where page will be variable from loop, and limit will be constant

Comment: Please provide more information about what you actually want. I doubt you just want to [replace something in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Do you know about [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and friends?

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial from scratch on how to do pagination - which is out of scope for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the string into an array then modify the required values and again create the string.

```
<?php
    $url = "domain.com/katalog_firm,p11.html?typ=lista&fraza=&search_group=1&search_type=1&kategoria=1&podkategoria=0&wojewodztwo=0&miejscowosc=0&page=1&limit=10";
    $params = explode("?",$url,2);
    parse_str($params[1], $url_array);
    $url_array['page'] = 2;
    $url_array['limit'] = 5;
    $newparams = http_build_query($url_array);
    $newurl = $params[0]."?".$newparams;
 ?>
```

Comment: I have modified the code a bit. Previous code may create errors in modifying first parameters.